# assembly code confusion? stock at these two problems

Tags: assembly, pseudocode, flags

1. the value of status flag bits (0 or 1) after execution of the add instruction. explain

   ```
    mov bx, 8000h
    add bx, 8000h
    c  this should be 0 because carry flag is not changed?
    0  this should be 1 because the sum is not zero?
    s  this should be not signed?
    z  ?
   ```
2. convert the pseudo-code into assembly, assumes value are signed integers and short circuited evaluation is used. the code should be compact.

   ```
   if(eax<ecx) AND (ebx != edx) {
    mov edi, esi;
    add ebx, eax;
   }
   ```

I'm really lost at this anyone want give some guidance?

Comment: This is basic assembly, what exactly you don't understand? If you don't understand anything, you should read your course again and/or ask your tutor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, a homework. Jack Daniels in my veins says I should help you :)

1 0x8000 + 0x8000 = 0x10000. Result is 17 bits, thus but your register is only 16 bits. So, only 0x0000 will be stored in BX.
With this you will get the following flags set:
- OF is set (sum is greater than register can hold);
- CF is set (highest bit of the result is 1)
- PF is set (number is even)
- ZF is set (BX = 0)
- SF is not set (not a signed number)

2 (fasm syntax)

```
cmp eax, ecx
jge short @f
cmp ebx, edx
jz short @f
mov esi, edi
add eax, ebx
@@:
```

Comment: Thank so much sir, also sir can I email you, I just few minor problem to ask since you are the assembly expert? thank you!

Comment: also it's for midterm practice not HW